# Frame-independent animation in game developement on android

Tags: android, animation, frame

Ok so delta-time is 1/fps right? Say the fps was 50, then delta time would equal 1/50= 0.02. My question is that frame rate varies(one second it might be 50, another it might be 52). So say for one second the fps is 50, that means that delta time will be equal to 0.02, but the NEXT second the fps will be 52, but we don't know that yet. So our animations are being done with delta time of 1/50 but the fps is actually 52. Until the next second is finished we won't know that the fps has changed. This may not seem like a big deal if the changes are small, but if they become very big then we have a problem. So the thing is we are always doing calculations based on the previous second's fps. I want to know how to solve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're right that 1/fps = delta-time. However, fps isn't known at the present, and as you pointed out going about it this way would cause a problem! In practice, the formula is re-arranged such that 1/dt = fps.

So, we determine delta-time by determining how much time has passed since the last update( deltaTime = (CurrentTime - LastTime) ). If we were to have a variable that we add delta time to every every update (say, deltaCounter += deltaTime), and another variable which is a counter we add one to each update (Counter++), we would see that when deltaCounter is becomes equal to 1, the Counter variable is our fps for that second.

[Further Reading on Delta Time and its Implementation](https://www.scirra.com/tutorials/67/delta-time-and-framerate-independence)

Comment: The link you provided still has the same problem I mentioned.. And what do you mean how much has passed since the last update? Delta-time is how much time it TAKES for one update to complete is it not? And in order for your re arraned formula to work, you still need to know the delta time in the first place, which just takes us back to square one...

Comment: Basically I need a way to know the fps BEFORE HAND, so then I can calculate delta-time based on that, and for the next second use that delta-time for the calculations.

Comment: Can u elaborate on how delta time is time passed since last update? This would give you some amount of milliseconds right? Meaning when delta counter is equal to 1000, the counter variable at that point in would be the fps. Also you would need to recalculate delta time every single update for what you are doing. Am I correct?

Comment: What I mean by how much time since the last update is you take the system time in milliseconds and subtract the system time recorded in the last update. This is how you determine delta time in the first place, so we are not at square one! So yes, you recalculate the delta time every update in this way. When you divide ( 1 / deltaTime ) this will show you the relative increment for this frame. Say, you want a character to move left at a speed of 1 unit per second, 1/dT gives you how much it needs to move in one update, or frame. For n units per second, you need to move ( n * ( 1 / dT ) ) units!

Comment: Okay I tried this but there's a problem: Let's say for the sake of ease that a second has an fps of 10, and the dT is equal to 100 each time(it takes 100 milliseconds since the last update). Let's say you want to move 30 units per second. So you divide 1/100 which is 0.01. Then you multiply this by 30 which gives you 0.3. Now since the fps is 10 in my scenario, let's multiply 0.3 by 10. This gives you 3 units per second, not 30...

Comment: You need to convert either the deltaTime from milliseconds to seconds, or convert the 1 to 1000 ms such that your equation becomes dT = (1000 /100) or dT = ( 1 * (0.1) )  or just dT = (0.1) to simplify. Then, when you do move 30 units it would be move =  (30 * (1000 / 100) ), which would be 3 units per frame or 30 units per second.